# Dans quelle situation utilise-t-on le subjonctif ?

Tags: grammaire, questions, subjonctif, mode-grammatical

Par exemple :

> Je ne crois pas que *+ subjonctif*
>
> Je ne crois pas que tu puisses la laisser tomber.

Toutefois, dans le livre « Latitudes 2 » à la page 94, il y a cette phrase:

> Vous ne croyez pas que j'ai gagné 150000 euros ?

Pourquoi n'ont-ils pas utilisé le subjonctif ?

Dans quelle situation utilise-t-on le subjonctif ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Premièrement, ne pas exclure la faute d'orthographe. Le subjonctif aurait été « que j'aie gagné » qui a la même prononciation.

Deuxièmement, ce contexte est un contexte où l'indicatif et le subjonctif sont tous deux possibles. Même [l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#83_strong-em-subordonne-relative-indicatif-ou-subjonctif-em-strong) est peu normative quand elle traite de ce sujet (pour la situation présente, elle dit *le subjonctif est plus habituel*).

Pour la question plus générale... Grevisse a dix pages sur ce sujet, plus un certains nombres de mentions ailleurs que le subjonctif s'utilise après telle ou telle conjonction.  La valeur fondamentale est que *le subjonctif indique que le locuteur ne s'engage pas sur la réalité du fait*. En pratique il est obligatoire dans certains contextes quel que soit le degré de certitude du locuteur, et quand il introduit une nuance par rapport à l'indicatif, ce n'est pas toujours une absence d'engagement sur la réalité du fait.

Answer (score 2):

On utilise le subjonctif quand la phrase est subjective.

Ici, la phrase n'est pas subjective, la personne qui l'a dite est normalement censée savoir ce qu'elle a gagné.

On utilise donc l'indicatif.