# Usage du subjonctif : « La subjectivité totale »

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

La P77 dans Advanced French Grammar de V. Mazet maintient ce qui suit :

> **Total Subjunctivity**
>
> The subjunctive can also be triggered by the underlying tone one wants to impart to the sentence-without the use of a trigger verb. It can express someone's intellectual or emotional input or his or her subjectivity (highlighted in the following examples).
>
> Mon espoir est que ce travail soit meilleure = My hope is that this work can be better.
> L'idéal serait que nous vivions sur une île tropicale. = The ideal (life) would be if we could live on a tropical island.

De plus, j'ai consulté [Le subjonctif sert-il à quelque chose ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/912/le-subjonctif-sert-il-a-quelque-chose/914#914) et [Dans quelle situation utilise-t-on le subjonctif ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/dans-quelle-situation-utilise-t-on-le-subjonctif/6448#6448).

Si je devais synthétiser cet extrait, je prétendrais : Pourvu que les règles au sujet du subjonctif ne s'appliquent pas dans une situation, on a le droit d'y choisir librement d'employer le subjonctif ou non pas. Est-ce correct ?

Comment: Je me répète, mais étant donné que ces verbes ne formulent pas une affirmation, je serais choqué par l'indicatif dans ces cas là.

Answer (score 1):

Les alternatives au subjonctif ne manquent pas, et on a toujours le droit de les utiliser. Ce choix peut être guidé entre autres choses par le niveau de langage et le style que l'on souhaite donner à la phrase.

> *L'idéal serait que nous vivions sur une île tropicale.* -> *Ce serait idéal de vivre sur une île tropicale.*

De la même façon,

> *Mon espoir est que ce travail soit meilleur.* -> *J'espère que ce travail est de meilleur qualité que précédemment/que l'autre.*

(Note relative à *que précédemment/que l'autre* : on choisira l'une de ces alternatives en fonction de ce à quoi *meilleur* s'applique)

Pour se référer à d'autres exemples, issus de [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/912/le-subjonctif-sert-il-a-quelque-chose/914#914) que tu références :

> *C'est important que vous soyez gentil.* -> *Votre gentillesse a/aura une grande importance.*

(Note relative à *a/aura* : en fonction du contexte, on peut être en train de parler d'une situation observée comme d'une situation espérée)

Concernant les expressions, il y a également des alternatives:

> *Dieu soit loué !* -> *Dieu doit être remercié et recevoir nos louanges.*

Et concernant [cette autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/dans-quelle-situation-utilise-t-on-le-subjonctif/6448#6448) référencée dans la tienne, et suivant le contexte :

> *Je ne crois pas que tu puisses la laisser tomber.* -> *Je serais surpris si tu la laissais tomber.* 
>   *Je ne crois pas que tu puisses la laisser tomber.* -> *Dans sa situation, je crois que tu ne peux pas la laisser tomber.*

(Dans le premier cas, *que tu puisses* a pour sens *qu'il te ressemblerait de*. Dans le second, *que tu puisses* a pour sens *qu'il te soit possible sans conséquences fâcheuses*.)

Enfin, et ce sera le dernier exemple :

> *Vous ne croyez pas que j'aie gagné 150 000 euros ?* -> *Vous ne semblez pas me croire lorsque j'annonce avoir gagné 150 000 euros.*

Il ne s'agit ici que d'exemples de reformulation. Il en existe bien d'autres pour ces mêmes phrases. Pour autant, le simple remplacement du subjonctif par l'indicatif n'est pas suffisant car le sens de la phrase pourrait s'en trouver modifié (cela a déjà été traité dans les questions liées).

Answer (score 0):

Si j'ai bien compris votre conclusion, je dirais que le subjonctif ne convient pas forcément à toutes les phrases.

Il est vrai qu'il y a parfois un choix, pour dire des choses différentes :

Imagine que tu m'**attendes** plusieurs années... (on est dans l'imagination)

J'imagine que tu m'**attends** là. (Même si il y a 'imagine' cette phrase n'exprime pas un doute)

Ou comme dans l'exemple présent dans le post mentionné (Shahgholi) en allant un peu plus loin :

Je ne crois pas que tu **puisses** la laisser tomber

Je ne crois pas que tu **peux** la laisser tomber (elle en sait trop sur toi)

on traduit avec ces modes un degré de réalité différent même si c'est parfois dificile à voir :

Le fait que tu **es** mon ami ne t'autorise pas à me parler ainsi

Le fait que tu **sois** mon ami ne t'autorise pas à ma parler ainsi

alors c'est l'usage qui prend le pas

Pour autant, cela ne signifie pas que l'on peut employer le subjonctif à tout va. (toujours dans le cas où j'ai compris votre affirmation)

Comment: Merci. Vous avez écrit : « Je ne crois pas que tu peux la laisser tomber ». Néanmoins, car le verbe croire est au négatif ici, d'après une règle, il faut forcément employer le subjonctif ? Je pige que dans vos autres exemples, on peut choisir.